# How to version CSS file in Webpack and update manifest?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a webpack config that has multiple JS entry points. In one of those entry points, I am requiring my styles: `require('../sass/app.scss');` and then using a loader to extract the styles into another file `app.css`.

```
test: /\.scss$/,
    loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: 'style-loader',
        use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
    })
```

And that is working great. Of course, we are having issues with old styles being served when we deploy because they are not being versioned like our JS. I have been searching around for a few hours on how to do this and I cannot find a source on how to not only version the CSS, but also get a manifest file for the CSS. I tried creating a new instance of the versioning plugin that I am using, but it only created a manifest for the JS files. I am assuming that since I only have an `output` for JS that is the reason for this. Anyhow, here is my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const CommonsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const VersioningPlugin = require('versioning-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackMd5Hash = require('webpack-md5-hash');
const routes = require('./resources/assets/js/routes');

module.exports = {
    entry: routes,
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public/js'),
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash:6].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader?presets[]=env',
                exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader',
                })
            }

        ],
    },
    plugins: [

        new CommonsPlugin({
            minChunks: 3,
            name: 'common'
        }),

        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 3000,
            proxy: 'napaautocarepro.dev',
            files: [
                'public/css/app.css',
                {
                    match: ['public/js/*.js', 'app/**/**/*.php', 'resources/views/**/**/*.php'],
                    fn: function(event, file) {
                        this.reload();
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, {
            injectChanges: true,
            reload: false
        }),

        new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/app.css'),

        new VersioningPlugin({
            cleanup: true,
            basePath: 'js/',
            manifestPath: path.join(__dirname, 'public/manifest.json')
        }),

        new WebpackMd5Hash()
    ]
};
```

And here is my `weback.prod.config.js`:

```
const config = require('./webpack.config');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');


config.plugins.unshift(
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['js', 'css'], {
        root: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        verbose: true,
        dry: false,
    }),

    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        compress: {
            warnings: false
        },
        comments: false,
        sourceMap: true
    }),

    new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
        assetNameRegExp: /\.css$/g,
        cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
        canPrint: true,
        cssProcessorOptions: { discardComments: { removeAll: true } }
    })

);

module.exports = config;
```

**How in the world can I version my CSS file and get it into a manifest so I can autoload the correct version?**

Answer (score 1):

Add `[chunkhash]` to the name of the file, something like:

```
plugins: [
   //...
   new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/app.[chunkhash].css'),
   //...
]
```

(from https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#options )

Comment: "on the CSS, but also get a manifest file for the CSS. I tried creating a new instance of the versioning plugin that I am using, but it only created a manifest for the JS files." That is from my original question. I can get a CSS file with a hash but I can't get a manifest with it to point to that file.